# Why is Breath of the Wild rated M?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I saw a few pictures and a fight part while I watched a video of "how to revive horses" before I realized it was rated M. Why is it rated M? It doesn't look that bad.  Ocarina of Time is rated G and that had dark things and I saw some comments in play through videos while I was playing it and some of them said it was scary and I think the N64 one had blood in it!

I want a good explanation of why I can't get it because it's rated M.

Comment: if this is Australia then the reason is because the Australian Rating Board is far stricter than most countries/ but there are times where it hatd to belive they know what they know what they are doing as the same group rated the [remake of Atelier Rorona, which was originally PG, R18+](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/726469-atelier-rorona-plus-the-alchemist-of-arland/69325907)

Comment: I completely agree that Ocarina Of Time is darker than people give it credit for (which I suspect is probably because of the dated graphics). I defy anyone to tell me that [dead](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NSDtuggHaQI/Ul2WSPdKwVI/AAAAAAAAApY/Wxr1nsYASgQ/s1600/Dead+Hand+Grab+Link+Ocarina.bmp) [hands](https://fafnirfang.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/dead_hand_close-up.jpg) and [redeads](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-bUcgpbVq2i0/UmwejStKyjI/AAAAAAAAAwQ/JPrCoXpFds4/s1600/ReDead+Ocarina+of+Time.jpg) are child friendly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how a certain region would classify it's games.  We are not the rating board; we have no way of knowing how they classify games.

Answer (score 14):

[In the US's rating standards, Breath of the Wild is rated E 10+](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/Synopsis.aspx?Certificate=34749&Title=The+Legend+of+Zelda:+Breath+of+the+Wild).  (very mild spoilers in this link, as they quote certain dialog lines to explain the rating)

[In Europe, it is rated PEGI-12](https://www.igdb.com/games/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/age_rating).

[In Australia, it is rated M](http://www.classification.gov.au/Pages/View.aspx?sid=Jy+Q81nX+v6eAHWtlLEORQ%3D%3D)

Australia's classification body tends to be a bit more strict than the US or European bodies.  For a borderline title like Breath of the Wild (moderate violence, alcohol usage, mild sexual allusions, etc), it's not surprising that Australia applied a slightly stronger rating to the game.

It's not about being dark or scary.  It's mainly about the intensity of the combat, and also somewhat the mildly controversial nature of some of the events portrayed in the game.

If it makes you feel any better, the previous two Legend of Zelda games, "Twilight Princess" and "Skyward Sword" also received "M" ratings in Australia.  It's also worth noting that "Ocarina of Time" is not rated "G" in Australia, but "PG", which is only one step down from M in the Australian system.

Comment: Isn't Australia super picky about games too? I thought most GTAs were banned there.

Comment: @TimmyJim no all the GTA to my understanding have been released in Australia. i brought GTA, GTA3, GTA:VC, GTA:SA, GTA:LSS and GTAIV locally and i can't see GTAV being banned considering that it appears on the Aus PSN Store while Monster Monpeice which was refused classification in Australia doesn't appear

Comment: "It's not about being dark or scary." Isn't that what these ratings are _supposed_ to be about? 

Comment: @JopV. That's a really interesting question!  Media ratings are mostly about trying to apply a community's cultural norms to protect their children;  to prevent them from accessing certain content that the culture thinks is harmful before a certain age.  Different cultures care about different things.  The USA rates nudity strictly.  France rates violence strictly.  Australia rates drug use strictly.  Germany rates blood strictly.  And so on.  (actually, France and Germany are both under PEGI now, so they have the same ratings.  But historically.)

Comment: @TrevorPowell Germany is still using their own rating system actually.

Comment: @JopV. Gah, you're right.  It's common to see PEGI ratings on games sold in Germany, but Germany does indeed use their own system, [USK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unterhaltungssoftware_Selbstkontrolle).  For completeness, Breath of the Wild is rated USK 12, in Germany;  it matches the PEGI 12 rating in the rest of Europe.